# After modifying Excel Sheets via python, graphs and charts disappears

Tags: python, excel

when I try to write data into an already existing excel Sheet, then the existing charts and pie charts in that excel sheet disappears.

Any code to do that via python is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible using openpyxl (as of 2016-11-22), and based on my googling I don't think it's possible using anything else either, though I could be wrong.

[Here is the bug for openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/523/charts-in-existing-worksheets-lost). It is scheduled to be fixed in version 2.5 (they're currently on 2.4)

There's already some code written to read charts, I'm not sure if it works yet though. More info at the link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: np! had the same question myself.